# Element following mouse [Eye effect]

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a div inside another div moving to the direction of my mouse, however it should never leave the div it's inside and that is exactly what it does. Is there a way to get it stuck inside the other div?

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('#pupil').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
});
```

```css
#eye {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 68px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  top: 132px;
  background-color: black;
}
#pupil {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
#eye2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 66px;
  width: 78px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  top: 125px;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
#pupil2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="eye">
  <div id="pupil"></div>
</div>
<div id="eye2">
  <div id="pupil2"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0087j9y/3/) aswell!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: this is a bit more complicated than I think you're thinking.  You need to get a lot of numbers (mouse position, center of the eye position, center of the pupil position, maximum distance) then do a lot of math to it using tangents and other geometry.  I'd suggest looking into making an arrow (pupils) point to your pointer at all times first in a fixed position.  Then you can build on top of that.

Comment: So basically i would need a much greater knowledge than i got at the moment

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ntgCleaner i guess il delete my question then

Comment: Nothing you can't learn online ;)  It might take a little longer than you'd hope, but I know you can learn it

Comment: You have a good start.  I would advise trying to narrow down your attempt to smaller tasks.  The arrow idea is good.  Start there.  It'll lead you into converting x,y coords into degrees or radians.  Any time you get stuck, try a few different things, look it up online, and finally ask about that specific part of the problem on here or other forums.  It's achievable even without lots of previous knowledge.  It'll be difficult (because of many moving parts) but doable.

Comment: okey il try to learn to make an arrow point of the direction of my mouse at first and then try to follow the steps you told me, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone would like to be able to do this effect here is a late answer:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

var DrawEye = function(eyecontainer, pupil, eyeposx, eyeposy, eyer){
  $("#dolaneye").append("<div id='" + eyecontainer + "'><div id='" + pupil + "'></div></div>")
  
  eyecontainer = "#" + eyecontainer;
  pupil = "#" + pupil;
  
  $(eyecontainer).css({left:eyeposx, top:eyeposy});
  $(pupil).css({width:eyer*0.4,height:eyer*0.4});
  $(eyecontainer).css({width:eyer,height:eyer});
  $(pupil).css({position: 'relative', background: '#000000', 'border-radius':'50%'});
  $(eyecontainer).css({position:'absolute', background:'#FFFFFF', overflow:'hidden', 'border-radius': '50%'});
  
  // Initialise core variables
  var r = $(pupil).width()/2;
  var center = {
    x: $(eyecontainer).width()/2 - r, 
    y: $(eyecontainer).height()/2 - r
  };
  var distanceThreshold = $(eyecontainer).width()/2 - r;
  var mouseX = center.x, mouseY = center.y;
  
  // Listen for mouse movement
  $(window).mousemove(function(e){ 
    var d = {
      x: e.pageX - r - eyeposx - center.x,
      y: e.pageY - r - eyeposy - center.y
    };
    var distance = Math.sqrt(d.x*d.x + d.y*d.y);
    if (distance < distanceThreshold) {
      mouseX = e.pageX - eyeposx - r;
      mouseY = e.pageY - eyeposy - r;
    } else {
      mouseX = d.x / distance * distanceThreshold + center.x;
      mouseY = d.y / distance * distanceThreshold + center.y;
    }
  });
  
  // Update pupil location
  var pupil = $(pupil);
  var xp = center.x, yp = center.y;
  var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // change 1 to alter damping/momentum - higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp) / 1;
    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 1;
    pupil.css({left:xp, top:yp});    
  }, 1);
};
//460 620
var eye = new DrawEye("eye4", "pupil4", 460, 130, 56);
var eye = new DrawEye("eye5", "pupil5", 620, 130, 56);

});
```

```css
#dolan{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:320px;
 -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
        transform: scaleY(-1);
        filter: FlipV;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src = "https://i.ibb.co/bNRmT0p/Dolan.png" id = "dolan">
<div id="dolaneye"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```html
<style>
  #eye {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 68px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  top: 132px;
  background-color: black;
}
#pupil {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
#eye2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 66px;
  width: 78px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  top: 125px;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
#pupil2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
  </style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="eye">
  <div id="pupil"></div>
</div>
<div id="eye2">
  <div id="pupil2"></div>
</div>



<script>
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();

        var eyeWidth = $('#eye').width();
        var eye2Width = $('#eye2').width();

        var eyeHeight = $('#eye').height();
        var eye2Height = $('#eye2').height();

        var pupil = $('#pupil');
        var pupil2 = $('#pupil2');
        $(document).mousemove(function (e)
        {
            pupil.css('left', e.pageX * eyeWidth / windowWidth).css('top', e.pageY * eyeHeight / windowHeight);
        });

        $(document).mousemove(function (e)
        {
            pupil2.css('left', e.pageX * eye2Width / windowWidth).css('top', e.pageY * eye2Height / windowHeight);
        });
  </script>
```

Comment: does this stop the pupil from leaving the eye?

Comment: it actully does, the only problem is that it only works when im hovering the eye and not when im outside the eye

Comment: right. Sorry, it stops the pupils from leaving the eye, but also doesn't work when the mouse is outside the eye.

Comment: Ok i will fix that. I was thinking it must move only when mouse is on eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed` on the `#pupil`. https://jsfiddle.net/8m74okbe/

```
#pupil{
    position:fixed; 
    z-index:3;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:100px;
   background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: but it is supposed to stay in the black div and "look" towards where the mouse is at, not follow behind the mouse:)

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. I'll get to work on that.

Comment: No worries glad to get any suggestions